# Incorrect format of labels in custom dataset for multi-label classification

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to implement a custom `Dataset` for multi-label classification. That is, one element may have multiple classes simultaneously. I tried returning the one-hot encoded representation or the class indices from the dataset directly, but neither of them works.

- One-hot encoded produces `RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float` when calculating the loss.
- Returning labels produces `IndexError: Target 1 is out of bounds.` when calculating the loss.

Here's a dummy implementation:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset

n_classes = 3


class Data(Dataset):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0.0]]), torch.tensor([0.0] * n_classes)
        # return torch.tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0.0]]), torch.tensor(range(n_classes))

    def __len__(self):
        return 10


data_loader = DataLoader(Data())
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(4, n_classes), nn.ReLU())

loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

model.train()
for epoch in range(3):
    print('EPOCH {}:'.format(epoch))
    for inputs, labels in data_loader:
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I couldn't really find any documentation or tutorials for implementing this sort of dataset, and the base `Dataset` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Dataset) are quite terse as well. Am I missing something, or doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says you the labels should have type of long. Therefore, you should convert the labels to long type by:

```
loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels.long())
```

Keep in mind that: if you are using one-hot encoding with nn.CrossEntropyLoss then you are not doing it in the right way. the target in nn.CrossEntropyLoss must contain class indices

Comment: Right, this ends up in the same "Target out of bounds" error unfortunately.

Comment: For your example above it, when converting the labels to long type it works without errors. can you show what labels contains in your case? using : print(labels)

Comment: Oh my mistake, I must have messed up something while trying out the different setups. So this returning the OH-encoded data is indeed the proper way to go?

Comment: if you are using one-hot encoding with nn.CrossEntropyLoss then you are not doing it in the right way. the target in  nn.CrossEntropyLoss must contain class indices as mentioned in: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html

Comment: Yeah this is definitely starting to get figured out. I naïvely thought it would just apply the formula. Looking into BCE now. Thanks for the guidance!